# XMLTYPE ORA-31011: XML parsing failed without root element only nested elements

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-serialization, xmltype

I have a function in oracle that return a `XMLType`, but without root element because the root element can repeat, and I need that to use in another select with `XMLElements`

My function is:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT 
    RETURN XMLTYPE AS 
      
      vXML CLOB;
      vXML_TEMP CLOB;
      
    BEGIN
      vXML := '';
    
      FOR cI IN (
        SELECT
          '10' ALM_IN_CODIGO,
          '1' LOC_IN_CODIGO,
          'DE' NAT_ST_CODIGO
        FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          '10' ALM_IN_CODIGO,
          '2' LOC_IN_CODIGO,
          'DE' NAT_ST_CODIGO
        FROM DUAL
      ) LOOP
      
        SELECT
          (
            XMLSerialize(content
              XMLElement("Item" 
                , XMLForest(
                    cI.ALM_IN_CODIGO AS ALM
                  , cI.LOC_IN_CODIGO AS LOC
                  , cI.NAT_ST_CODIGO AS NAT
                ) Item
              ).extract('/*') indent
            ) 
          ) XML_BL_XML
          INTO vXML_TEMP
          FROM DUAL;
        
        vXML := vXML || vXML_TEMP;
        
      END LOOP;
      
      RETURN XMLTYPE.CreateXML(vXML);
    END F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT;
```

When I called that:

```sql
    SELECT
    MGCLI.F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT()
    FROM DUAL;
```

I received the error code

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
```

I think that's have a better way to make this work, but I don't know how

```xml
    <Item><ALM>10</ALM><LOC>1</LOC><NAT>DE</NAT></Item>
    <Item><ALM>10</ALM><LOC>2</LOC><NAT>DE</NAT></Item>
```

The right function is called in this select to make the entire `XML`

```sql
     SELECT
     XMLSerialize(content
        XMLElement("Group", XMLAttributes('I' AS "OP")
        , XMLForest(
              3 FIL
            , 59 TPD
        ) 
        , XMLElement("Obs"
            , XMLForest(
              'N' OB_CH_TYPE
              , (
                'Ref. '
              ) OB_ST_OBS
            )
          )
          , (
            SELECT
              XMLAgg(
                XMLElement("Item", XMLAttributes('I' AS "OP")
                  , XMLElement("ITN",1)
                  , MGCLI.F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT()
                )
              ) FROM DUAL
            )       
          ).extract('/*') indent
        ) XML_BL_XML
            FROM DUAL
            ;
```

Comment: Well, you don't show us the XML, so who knows. post a [mcve]

Comment: @OldProgrammer Sry, my bad, I just edit the question, but if you compile the function and make a call, it will popup the error I have... I made the code selfexplain

Comment: I made a function that return a XML like that and was called in another XMLElement, I can put the rest of the code if necessary

Comment: I think that maybe is not a function that I need... perhaps a procedure that returns the results to use in `XMLAgg`

Comment: i use a cursor in the function: `create or replace FUNCTION F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS 
  
  refC sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

  OPEN refC FOR
    SELECT
      '10' ALM,
      '1' LOC,
      'DE' NAT
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '10' ALM,
      '2' LOC,
      'DE' NAT
    FROM DUAL
  ;
  
  RETURN refC;
END F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT;`

Comment: but the result it's a little wrong: `<Group OP="I">
  <FIL>3</FIL>
  <TPD>59</TPD>
  <Obs>
    <OB_CH_TYPE>N</OB_CH_TYPE>
    <OB_ST_OBS>Ref. </OB_ST_OBS>
  </Obs>
  <Item OP="I">
    <ITN>1</ITN>
    <Item>
      <ROWSET>
        <ROW>
          <ALM>10</ALM>
          <LOC>1</LOC>
          <NAT>DE</NAT>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
          <ALM>10</ALM>
          <LOC>2</LOC>
          <NAT>DE</NAT>
        </ROW>
      </ROWSET>
    </Item>
  </Item>
</Group>
`

Answer (score 0):

XML documents must have a single root element, else they are not well-formed, and compliant XML parsers are required to report such a problem as an error.

Fix your XML by wrapping the multiple elements in a single root element.

Comment: I need to make a XML like this: `<Group> <FIL>4</FIL> <Item OP="I"> <ITN>1</ITN> <Item> <ALM>10</ALM> <LOC>1</LOC> <NAT>DE</NAT> </Item> <Item> <ALM>10</ALM> <LOC>2</LOC> <NAT>DE</NAT> </Item> </Group>`

Comment: The XML you posted in that comment is also not well formed.

Comment: Why? Is that i have to made to integrate with system

Comment: Unclosed `Item` element.

Comment: Oooh, that is because I wrote node by node and forgot to close one, I update the with the code that returns all

Answer (score 0):

I get one way to make what i want:

I change the function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT 
RETURN sys_refcursor AS 

  refC sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

  OPEN refC FOR
    SELECT
      '10' ALM,
      '1' LOC,
      'DE' NAT
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '10' ALM,
      '2' LOC,
      'DE' NAT
    FROM DUAL
  ;

  RETURN refC;
END F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT;
```

Then i change the primary `SELECT` to make the entire XML:

SELECT
     XMLSerialize(content

```
    XMLElement("Group", XMLAttributes('I' AS "OP")
    , XMLForest(
          3 FIL
        , 59 TPD
    ) 
    , XMLElement("Obs"
        , XMLForest(
          'N' OB_CH_TYPE
          , (
            'Ref. '
          ) OB_ST_OBS
        )
      )

      , (
        SELECT
          XMLAgg(
            XMLElement("Item", XMLAttributes('I' AS "OP")
              , XMLElement("ITN",1)
              , 
              (SELECT
                XMLAgg(
                  XMLElement("Item", 
                     XMLElement("ALM", ALM) 
                    ,XMLElement("LOC", LOC)
                    ,XMLElement("NAT", NAT)
                  )
                ) 
                FROM 
                XMLTABLE(
                  '/ROWSET/ROW'
                  PASSING XMLType(MGCLI.F_XML_WITHOUT_ROOT())
                  COLUMNS
                  ALM  PATH 'ALM',
                  LOC PATH 'LOC',
                  NAT PATH  'NAT'
                )
              ) 
            )
          ) FROM DUAL
        )

      ).extract('/*') indent
    ) XML_BL_XML
        FROM DUAL;
```

And the result:

```
<Group OP="I">
  <FIL>3</FIL>
  <TPD>59</TPD>
  <Obs>
    <OB_CH_TYPE>N</OB_CH_TYPE>
    <OB_ST_OBS>Ref. </OB_ST_OBS>
  </Obs>
  <Item OP="I">
    <ITN>1</ITN>
    <Item>
      <ALM>10</ALM>
      <LOC>1</LOC>
      <NAT>DE</NAT>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ALM>10</ALM>
      <LOC>2</LOC>
      <NAT>DE</NAT>
    </Item>
  </Item>
</Group>
```

This is the best way i find, maybe has another...